# Django Debug Toolbar style is broken

Tags: python, django, django-debug-toolbar

I have installed django debug-toolbar, it can fetch the css and js but it still shows debug toolbar like below and also shows this at the end of the page instead of nearby, there is not js error in console. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: are you serving this from a server other then django dev server? If so , i think you have to route the static request to the django-debug-toolbar project

Comment: Statics are coming from s3 server and accessible, what should i do?

Comment: Yea now i serve statics from django dev server, and it fixed. thanks much..

Comment: I have the same problem except I only have a localhost instance running (i.e. my display looks the same as @tunaktunak).

I ran `collectstatic` but it didn't help.

I also tried placing the `'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',` first in the list and last in the list - still the same problem.

IMHO: It is relying on CSS which apparently isn't loading!?

Answer (score 3):

I was having this exact same issue. You don't need to switch to serving files locally, using S3 to serve your static files works just fine.

In my case (and likely in yours), you just need to run:

```
$ python manage.py collectstatic
```

That will update the static files—adding the files that the Debug Toolbar needs to render its styling correctly.